# Почему joins требует order (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Каждый раз, когда необходимо построить запрос с использованием `.joins` и `.select`, также необходимо указать в `.order` поле, которое использовалось в `.select`.

Рабочий запрос:

```
Information.joins(post: { blog: :company })
            .select('DISTINCT ON (blogs.company_id) *')
            .order('blogs.company_id, blogs.title DESC')
```

Проблема лишь в тому, что идет сортировка по `posts.author_id`, а мне это вообще не нужно... Мне нужна сортировка только по заголовку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Полнее, какие именно данные вы пытаетесь получить и из какой структуры. Кусок запроса не может быть рабочим уже потому, что это кусок.

Comment: join не требует сортировку. Но на уровне запроса вы запрашиваете `DISTINCT ON` - он сортировку требует т.к. как ему ещё понять, какую строку из подходящих считать первой

Comment: @D-side дополнил код.

Comment: @Мелкий а можно как-то после определения этой первой строки и отсечения остальных, указать ту сортировку, которая мне нужна. И уже выводить список именно с этой сортировкой?

Comment: *какие именно данные вы пытаетесь получить и из какой структуры* [2] ...и в каком порядке.

Comment: А `DISTINCT ON` довольно просто реализован: он обходит полный список строк последовательно и при каждом изменении значений выражений в `DISTINCT ON`, вычисленных на строчке, добавляет эту строчку в результат, а последующие равные пропускает (до очередного изменения). Чтобы алгоритм работал, строчки должны быть заранее сгруппированы по значениям этих же выражений. Поэтому требуют, чтобы `ORDER BY` начинался с того же.